# How can I get the style of the maps.google.com?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

maps.google.com has a custom style. How can I get that? Thanks so much
[image: I want to get this style]

Default google map uses circles for place makers, but I want to use pin icons like above. Anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries?[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), How much research effort is expected [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: _maps.google.com has a custom style. How can I get that?_. Do you actually mean how to modify the style of your map? If yes, this is how to  [get the styling reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference). For custom markers and icons [click here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers). It would be better to post the nitty gritty of your problem with code samples and specific questions

Answer (score 1):

The new style of tiles on maps.google.com you refer to was introduced by Google in November 2017. The corresponding blog post where Google described this change in their products can be found at

https://www.blog.google/products/maps/google-maps-gets-new-look/

Unfortunately, this new look is not available in Google Maps JavaScript API, Google Maps Android API or Google Maps SDK for iOS yet. However, according to the aforementioned blog post the new look will be available in APIs during next months:

> Over time, the new style will also appear in the apps, websites and experiences offered by companies that use Google Maps APIs as well.

Stay tuned and hopefully Google will announce the new style in APIs soon.

**UPDATE**

Google announced that new style will be available in Google Maps APIs very soon:

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2018/02/updated-basemap-style-for-google-maps.html

> **Google Maps SDK for iOS** - 13 February 2018
>
> **Google Places API for iOS** - 13 February 2018
>
> **Google Maps JavaScript API** - 14 February 2018 (version 3.32)
>
> **Google Static Maps API** - Mid February 2018
>
> **Google Maps Android API** - Early March 2018
>
> **Google Places API for Android** - May 2018